# How to export/package a group of files from Bazel

Tags: makefile, tar, bazel

This feels too obvious to be unanswered, but if the answer is out there, I haven't found it.  For context, I'm incorporating someone else's existing code into a Bazel build, so I'm really not looking for "just don't do it that way"-type answers.

The code produces man dozen related files:  Libraries, compiled binaries (from C and C++, if that matters), python and shell scripts, etc.  Those files expect to find each other in specific locations (e.g. shell scripts reference binaries by relative or absolute path), and I need to package up and install the whole lot.

Is there a way to do that in Bazel?  To pick out a bunch of bazel-generated files (and, in this case, a bunch of input files that we pass through unmodified) and put them in a tarball, or a standard package format (e.g. `.deb`) or even just place them in the local file system in known locations?

The closest ideas I've seen involve basically doing it by hand (e.g. writing a shell script to go into Bazel's output directory and copy out the files of interest) but that seems easy to get wrong.  There has to be a way to use the intelligence of the build system to bundle up a bunch of targets and data files, right?

Answer (score -1):

Naturally, I find what's probably the answer shortly after posting the question:  https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/pkg.html.  If anyone has further insight, though, I'm definitely happy to hear it!